Please provide your comments on this circuit idea of mine for bias generation?

There is a requirement for a P-side current generation. Currently we have P-side Vt/R solution which is the left branch in the figure, except it is diode connected. When the PMOS is diode connected, since the current ends up being VDD dependent, I thought of an idea where gate moves with VDD. Basically when VDD increases, current through R8 increases which raises the gate of the NMOS. That causes the NMOS to pull the gate of the PMOS current mirror down (diode connected side). This raises the current through the mirror.
On the side of the mirror with the resistor, the current increase raises the voltage on the resistor, which raises the gate of the PMOS. I assumed through this, VGS will move in conjunction with VDD. Will this help keep the current constant and does this look an idea at all, or have I made up a bunch of BS? Please provide your honest feedback.

Seeing that this is already entered into cadence, what does an ADE simulation say if you sweep VDS? How about if you run a corners simulation?

You have an image that is unreadable, has too much clutter and not enough definition. Apart from anything else it would be much better on a white background without all the grid dots on.
